# Blazor Server App cannot remove Identity Pages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor Server App.  It authenticates via SSO, so I have no need for Identity/Account/Login or Identity/Account/Register.  I have tried a number of things to remove them, but nothing seems to work. Things I have tried:

1. I have deleted the files, but the app seems to still redirect to them.
2. Reroute endpoints in Startup.cs Config method:

   ```
   app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
   { 
         //try to redirect to the home page   
         endpoints.MapGet("/Identity/Account/Register", context => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => context.Response.Redirect("/", true, true)));
         endpoints.MapPost("/Identity/Account/Register", context => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => context.Response.Redirect("/", true, true)));
        endpoints.MapControllers();
        endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
        endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");                
   });
   ```

All this does is redirect from the Register page to the Login page

3. Re-scaffold the Register/RegisterConfrimation/Login pages and updated them as this:

**Register.cshtm**

```
public class RegisterModel : PageModel
    {
        public IActionResult OnGet()
        {
          return Redirect("~/");
        }

        public IActionResult OnPost()
        {
            return Redirect("~/");
        }
    }
```

But this also just redirects to the Login page.

4. Update links to point to another page.  Yes, I can do this, but users can still type in the URL and go to the Login or Register pages

So, how do  I remove these pages so users cannot access them?

**Update**
It seems if I run my app in debug (Debug->Start Debugging) this works.  But, if I run it al control+F5 it does not work.  I'm not sure what the difference is?

Comment: Try deleting the bin folder and Rebuild All.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that but it does not change anything.

Comment: Did you find a solution yet? I have added the endpoints too with permanent=true. I cant get rid of the redirect since then (in Debugmode too).

Comment: @cpt.oneeye no, I never found a solution to this.

Comment: A potential solution could be to replace `AddDefaultIdentity()` with an `AddIdentity()` call, instead. Looking at their source code, they do mostly the same thing, except `AddDefaultIdentity()` also generates default UI endpoints. I'm not 100% sure this doesn't break anything else, though, so I'm hesitant to post it as a solution. Also, you'd need to implement the logic that comes with the UI yourself.